# How do I change my default charset from ANSI to Unicode in my project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I change my default charset from ANSI to Unicode in my project?
When I write special characters as Æ Ø Å in my view that is ANSI it renders a error.
But if I change the file to UTF-8 encoding it renders the special characters without a error. Should I then change all my view files from ANSI encoding to UTF-8 ?

Comment: Can you describe your problem? I didn't have to change a thing to use unicode.

Comment: Yes, you should change all view files from ANSI to UTF-8, cause using ANSI is an old standard.

Comment: Can I set  utf 8 as default in rails when creating a new project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some rails magic - add this comment to your .rb file:

```
# coding: utf-8
```

and it should work)

You also can use Iconv class to convert your string to UTF-8 like this:

```
require 'iconv'
ic = Iconv.new('WINDOWS-1251','UTF-8')
new_string = ic.iconv(old_string)
```